# Make UI5 progress indicator accessible

Tags: javascript, sapui5

SAPUI5 provides progress indicator. https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/progress-indicator/

I am using JAW screen reader for my app. Since progress indicator is not a link, it is not accessible via tab bar.

Is there any work around to make progress indicator accessible by space bar?
I have already tried area-labelled-by tag, but it is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: I try to understand the issue.
You want to move the “mouse pointer” to the progress indicator via tab key on your keyboard and then “click” on it using the space bar on your keyboard?
And then you would like to get text-to-speech output from the progress-indicator?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Jaws are you using? In which mode are you (virtual mode or application mode) ? 
Application mode is UI5 default and here it should work as long as the ProgressIndicator is focusable (beware of some properties e.g. "displayOnly" which disable focus).

Sometimes there are strange effects with some constellations of controls that are direct neighbors in the DOM. Try to encapsulate the "misbehaving" control in an other layout control like Panel or Vbox. This might help avoiding these effects.